# How to format dates in conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table Mnt_Items that store the date for the last maintainance done in last_mnt. Also the table store the number of days between maintainances in mnt_frequence.
I want to make a view that present all items that needs to be maintained, but I get the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "23": syntax error: SELECT "mnt_items".* FROM "mnt_items" WHERE (last_mnt > 2013-06-22 23:58:41 UTC)
```

My model and controller are as follows:

```
class MntItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :needs_maintain, :conditions => "last_mnt > "  + -20.days.from_now.to_s
end

class MntItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @mnt_items = MntItem.needs_maintain

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @mnt_items }
  end
end
```

Any suggestions what causes the error, or how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the date value inside single quotes (')?

Comment: Gylaz gave me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let rails do the work for you:

```
scope :needs_maintain, -> (day_count) { where('last_mnt > ?', day_count.days.from_now) }
```

Then call it:

```
MntItem.needs_maintain(20)
```

Comment: Can I ask you, if I want the hardcoded "20" to be replaced by mnt_frequence, how could I implement it?

Comment: I meant, let rails handle the conversion of Date object to SQL query format. I updated the example to show how to pass a value. Also, use `scope` instead of `named_scope`.